# Handling UITableView delegates when the UITableview is a subview of a Custom UIView

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, custom-view

I have a UITableView as a subview of my CustomView.

I have initialised my custom view and since the UITableview is an outlet of my CustomView, I am trying to set the delegates of the UITableview in my main view controller.

The UITableView delegates is not being called. My UIView is initialised from the NIB file.

How do I make my ViewController to handle the Delegates of my CustomView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check that you have set the:

```
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.datasource = self;
```

where `self` is the controller.

Comment: you should remember that when you have implemented the delegates for any control and they are not getting invoked, in 99% cases the problem tend to be with setting the delegate/datasource so you should start your debugging with checking for this as first step

Answer (score 0):

First: the `MainViewController` must implement the `UITableviewDatasource`, and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols. Then, check that the delegate and datasource you set to the tableView is a correct instance of the `MainViewController`. If you connect the delegate and datasource of the table view from the Interface builder, maybe you have to import the `"MainViewController.h"` in your `CustomView` (if I understood correctly). Hope it's helping u!